# Disable USB port power/charging functionality while keeping its data transfer abilities

Tags: android, linux, embedded, usb

Is it technically possible to disable an USB ports power/charging functionality so that it does not charge/give power to the connected device while still being able to send data/commands to the device that connected through USB?

I've read some posts that say that according to the USB spec this is impossible while others say that it is possible but don't explain how.

I've already tried using uhubctl but that completely disables an USB port instead of only disabling its charging capabilities while preserving its data transfer abilities.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on how the external device is powered, naturally. Is the question how to disable the power lines through software in Linux? I don't know how/if that's possible, but you could just use a cable without those wires connected.

Comment: This is not the place for this question.  The right place already has an answer.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7256/usb-without-vcc.  The correct way to prevent charging is in the device hardware design to only use USB Vcc as signalling and not as a power supply power.  The USB controllers Vbus input will itself draw very little current.  That is you need Vbus connected to the controller but you do not need to actually draw power.

Comment: According to the specifications you may connect a self-powered device. In that case it won’t use VBUS from the host.

Answer (score 0):

XHCI will disable the port when power is disabled. I'm guessing that you still want to be able to transfer data and have your device stop charging or stop powering another device? There is a long open bug with Google to be able to control this without root access to help extend battery longevity. I use a device called Chargie to limit how much my battery charges, unfortunately, it appears that data transfer is not possible when charging is disabled through it.